# Pre-populate payment information in PayPal Here from a web app?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-here

Is it possible to open PayPal Here with a particular invoice or payment amount pre-populated?  I am trying to enable a smooth workflow from a mobile web app to PayPal to swipe a credit card.

For example, can you create a deep link into the PayPal Here app?  Or notify the PayPal REST API to open a recently created invoice directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this [Sideloader Api](https://github.com/paypal/here-sideloader-api-samples/blob/master/docs/README.md#sending-an-invoice-to-the-paypal-here-mobile-app). It also have 3 samples project that will get you started.

Comment: I have tried the sideloader but it is giving me an error. Can you assist?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604228/paypal-here-java-integration